# Cedilla (ç) not being mapped correctly only on Emacs, how do I map it correctly? And why is this happening?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, gtk3

I've been using the US International keyboard layout for typing the cedilla character (`ç`)  — and other Portuguese characters; and other bizarro other accidental ones — for a while, and it works on basically all of my applications. In order to correctly set it up though, I had to alter some files inside my Artix OS. You can find more about it through these links:

- [Nilo's Gist for "How to use Cedilha on US Keyboard on ArchLinux"](https://gist.github.com/nilo/c2a31a0f9f29c88145ca)
- [My own, more readable version of Nilo's Gist](https://github.com/psygo/dotfiles/blob/master/.notes/cedilla.md)

Sometimes, when there is a system upgrade, I have to redo the steps in those gists, but that's about it, it works in the end.

I'm using GUI Emacs — I didn't even know there was a way of using Emacs on the terminal... — with GTK and X11, with XMonad as my WM. You can find out more about my setup [here](https://github.com/psygo/dotfiles).

However, the major problem is that the mapping doesn't work at all within Emacs. It maps to the original `ć`, which I guess is a Slav character, but I don't really know. How do I fix this? And why is this happening *only* in Emacs?

Comment: What user interface are you using: terminal or GUI emacs and if GUI with which toolkit (Lucida, GTK, …), console or X11, what window manager or desktop environment, …?

Comment: I'm using GUI Emacs — I didn't even know there was a way of using Emacs on the terminal... — with GTK and X11, with XMonad as my WM. You can find out more about my setup [here](https://github.com/psygo/dotfiles).

Comment: A bit of workaround: you can change input type in Emacs with C-\ and then select latin-pre-1. Cedilha would then be `,c`. This only works with Emacs and you have to set it at least per session, but it's what I use to add non-english characters when needed. You should be able to select almost any kind of input (but I prefer the pre option).

Comment: @miguelbernadi, weirdly, `C-\ ` isn't working actually. Even if I select something like `portuguese-prefix`, it gets superseeded by whatever layout I selected using `setxkbmap`. And I couldn't find `latin-pre-1`, the closest I got was `latin-1-prefix`.

Comment: You are right, I referred to `latin-prefix` or `latin-1-prefix`. Citing from memory was not a good idea. Once you select that didn't it work combining `,` and `c`? It does work in my Emacs.